# MongoDB - Update All Map Values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents that are structured like this:

```json
    // Document 1
    
        { 
          _id : "910",
          requests : {
            100 : {
              date : "10/06/2022 11:24:19"
              isProcessed : false
            },
            123 : {
              date : "10/06/2022 11:24:19"
              isProcessed : false
            },
          }
        }
    
    // Document 2

        { 
          _id : "743",
          requests : {
            999 : {
              date : "10/06/2022 11:24:19"
              isProcessed : false
            },
            152 : {
              date : "10/06/2022 11:24:19"
              isProcessed : false
            },
          }
        }
```

requests are saved as a map structure and the keys are different in each document. I want to change `isProcessed` to `true` in every value of every field in the `requests` map, and do it for all the documents. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your documents/schema design.

1. Using dynamic value as field names is generally considered as anti-pattern
2. You are storing dates as strings. Consider storing them as proper date objects

Nevertheless, You can use `$objectToArray` to convert the `requests` object into an array of k-v tuples. Then use `$mergeObjects` to perform the update of `isProcessed` flag. Finally, use `$arrayToObject` to revert back to original structure.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "requests": {
        "$objectToArray": "$requests"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "requests": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$requests",
          "as": "kv",
          "in": {
            k: "$$kv.k",
            v: {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$kv.v",
                {
                  "isProcessed": true
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "requests": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$requests"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zBdepVe2jQC) for your reference,

Comment: Why is it considered anti-pattern?

Comment: @YahliGi Because it will make all the queries unnecessarily complicated. You can see you will need `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to convert into k-v tuple array, perform the processing, then convert back into objects. This can be avoided by storing directly as something like `{"requestId": 999, "requestBody": {"date": "10/06/2022 11:24:19", "isProcessed": false} }`. Another thing is you must store field name as strings. You can also avoid string to numeric conversion for the id field.

Comment: @YahliGi Your `date` field is also very messy. It is not standard ISO format. This will make it very difficult to convert into proper date objects by using `$convert` or `$date` if you need to use date API to perform aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! Small question, if I know I have data that I won't have to do complex queries on, and in the client side it would be helpful for me to have a Map (instead of doing iterations, just to map get()), why shouldn't I do it?

Comment: @YahliGi It would be more lenient and less necessary if complex queries are not required. However, I still foresee some difficulties in manipulating the array as you may need to parse the keys(i.e. 100, 123...) to filter and update those array elements. Using static value as field name should save you some effort for doing so, even if you are doing it at javascript level.

Comment: Hmm I see your point. Thanks a lot!